# SQL to Count/Sum into multiple groups

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table:

`account | amount | date_time`

How do I get the following report?

`count_0-10_days, amount_0-10_days, count_10-20_days, amount_10-20_days, count_20-30_days, amount_20-30_days`

I currently use the `UNION` and do multiple sub queries, but I am wondering if there is a better and most efficient way of doing it?

Comment: Can you provide the calculations you are using?  i.e. is the 0 to 10 days current_date - date ?

Comment: Please show sample data and expected output of the sample data and your query.

Comment: Conditional aggregating, e.g sum(case when date < 10 days then 1 else else 0 end)

Comment: Can you provide sample data and include the SQL up to what you have working so that we can take a look and make suggestions based on your request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use the Sum( Case ) in your select? Be sure to use the correct date pattern if your date is a non standard date format. Without a sample of the data this is the best i can suggest. Below is how you can do this for the 0-10 case, repeat for other date ranges you would like.

```
Select 
    SUM( CASE WHEN [date_time] between TO_DATE([date_time], 'date pattern') AND TO_DATE([date_time], 'date pattern')-10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS 'count_0-10_days',
    SUM( CASE WHEN [date_time] between TO_DATE([date_time], 'date pattern') AND TO_DATE([date_time], 'date pattern')-10 THEN amount ELSE 0 END ) AS 'amount_0-10_days'
From [Table_name]
```

Comment: `[date_time]` is an invalid identifier in SQL.

Comment: i used the field names provided by the poster and surrounded them with square brackets to indicate there use. I am not sure the field names the poster provided are the actual field names. Also Table_name was pseudo code as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
select start_date,end_date,(rownum-1)*10+1||'-'||rownum*10 days, amount 
from 
    (
        select dr.start_date,dr.end_date,sum(t.amount) amount
            from (
                    select ((trunc(to_date(<start_date>,'dd-mon-yyyy')))+(rownum-1)*10) start_date, 
                        ((trunc(to_date(<start_date>,'dd-mon-yyyy')))+(rownum)*10)-1 end_date
                    from dual connect by rownum < 366
                 ) dr, <table_name> t
        where
            to_date(trunc(t.date_time), 'dd-mon-yyyy') between dr.start_date and dr.end_date
        group by dr.start_date,dr.end_date
    );
```